# How to switch from Hybrid flow to ResourceOwner flow with IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I need to upgrade (or downgrade) my Website to using a local login page.  I had it all working using the hybrid flow using the following code

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions(){});
```

And then when the token would come back, it would give me access to complete the authentication logic in asp.net- setting the claims identity, principal, etc.

```
  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
            {

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                    {
                       // perform transform, etc..

                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                            identity, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                        await Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Now, I am going to be collecting the username and password from an MVC action method.  I am able to get the access token from the client this way.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        var client = new TokenClient(
            StsSettings.TokenEndpoint,
            ClientId,
            Secret);

        var x = client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, "customid openid").Result;

        return View(model);
    }
```

But I'm not sure how the easiest way to tell ASP.NET to point to my custom login page instead of an identity server.  Would I use forms authentication logic and create some AuthenticationTicket?  Also, what is the best way set the `ClaimsIdentity` (I know how to get the claims back, just need a "hook")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the outcome of the resource owner password flow to be the logged in user, you need to issue the main authentication cookie with the claims you have for that newly authenticated user.

`var claims = new Claim[] {
     new Claim("name", username),
     new Claim("sub", "4848784904"),
     new Claim("email", "BrockAllen@gmail.com"),
     new Claim("role", "Admin"),
     new Claim("role", "Dev"),
};
// "Cookies" is the name of your cookie middleware, 
// so change to match what you're actually using in Startup.cs
var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookies", "name", "role");
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(ci);
return Redirect("~/Home/Secure");`

Comment: worked like a charm!  Thank you, and on a personal note, thank you for all your hard work for IdentityModel and IdentityServer and MembershipReboot!!